# How to fix this columns

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

> It's been a while since I used CSS. I need help with making the column
> better. I would like the 2nd row to be aligned. Photos to be of the
> same size. And please advise what to do if I decide to make it 3
> columns in a row. I will attach a photo of what it looks
> like.[image: Column]

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
div.a {font-size: 14px;}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: min;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  /*display: table;*/
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of 
next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="">
<img src="/uploads/agent-7/1172.jpg" style="width:100%">
<em>1172 Victory Blvd Staten Island, NY</em>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="">
    <img src="/uploads/agent-7/Cover_2040_Victory_23.jpg" style="width:100%">
<em>2040 Victory Blvd Staten Island, NY</em>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="column" style="">
<img src="/uploads/agent-7/123_Monroe_.jpg" style="width:100%">
<em>123 Monroe Ave Staten Island, NY</em>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="">
    <img src="/uploads/agent-7/465_Albany_Shaker_Road_.jpg" style="width:100%">
<em>465 Albany Shaker Rd Colonie, NY</em>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your images aren't all the same height.  Change the .column css height to a specific size and it will align properly, (presuming the image isn't bigger than the height you specify. You might need to use an overflow parameter or an auto-width for really big images.)

Comment: great point! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.row:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
```

}

and maybe don't use left float
(haven't USD HTML in a while)

Comment: How do I make it 3 columns in a row?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: layout is like this

Comment: <div class="row">
        <div class="column"><img class="image" src="img/eddie_full.jpg" width="370" height="270">
        </div>
        <div class="column"><img class="image" src="img/eric_full.jpg" width="370" height="270">
        </div>
        <div class="column"><img class="image" src="img/leo_full.jpg" width="370" height="270">
        </div>